# Bootstrap navbar doesn't work

Tags: navbar

I'm building a web site using Bootstrap 3. On mobile version the collapse, hide the header part of the page.

You can see the screen shot here:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7kEC5-m4btFclBpQUNxTWZLVkU

What is the correct way to solve the problem?
Thank you in advance,
Regards,
Roberto

Answer (score 0):

use clearfix class before search box divition....like this

```
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I add clearfix class before box division but it doesn't work..

I spent time to research solution about clearfix class adn implementation, but without solution. You can see complete html code here:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7kEC5-m4btFTllGSFREOEV5alk

Can you help me, please? Regards, Roberto